# Multiple htaccess files per website?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any utility in having multiple `.htaccess` files in different folders? Or should there really only be one file per website or domain? Thanks.

[edit]

My question is with regard to multiple `.htaccess` files in *different* folders, not the *same* folder. E.g. each sub-folder with its own `.htaccess` file, plus another one in the root folder.

Also, the "duplicate" that was linked to talks about trying to disable one file and enable the other depending on which server is hosting the site, which I am not trying to do.

[edit]

Note that I have not noticed any problems with the way I'm doing things now. I am just wondering if there are consequences I might *not* be aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple htaccess files in one folder, or conditional AuthType Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101367/multiple-htaccess-files-in-one-folder-or-conditional-authtype-basic)

Comment: Not a duplicate. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have multiple .htaccess files in multiple/different folders.

Comment: It's not an answer !!!! Explain more with an example or a way to do that

Comment: But what I want to know is, is it better to combine them all into one file in the root directory? Does it matter? IIRC, someone on this site mentioned it would be better to only have one such file, but I don't remember who said this or in what thread.